# How to create a global razor variable to keep count of length in array

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

How can I create a global variable in razor that keeps track of the count of `SuccessCriteria`? I am dynamically creating form inputs for `SuccessCriteria` when the `insert-success-criteria` button is clicked and removing the last one created when the `remove-success-criteria` button is clicked. As a result I need something like `model => model.SuccessCriteria[count]` with `count` being incremented when an input is added and decremented when an input is removed.

I tried `@{int count = 1; }` above my functions but this stores it locally and I cannot access it within my function

Also, is there a way to set the element of an array to null when I remove it?
I tried `@{SuccessCriteria[count] = null;}` however that does not work.

Model:

```
    public int SuccessCriteriaId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Success Criteria/ROI:")]
    public virtual List<String> SuccessCriteria { get; set; }
```

View:

```
<table>
<tr class="form-group col-xs-12">
    <td class="form-label col-xs-4">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SuccessCriteria, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-xs-12" })
    </td>
    <td class="form-input col-xs-8">
        <ul>
            <li class="base-success-criteria">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SuccessCriteria[0], new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control col-xs-12" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SuccessCriteria, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </li>
       </ul>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr class="form-group col-xs-12">
    <td class="form-label col-xs-4"></td>
        <td class="form-input col-xs-8">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" id="insert-success-criteria"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></i></button> Insert another measurement
         </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
@{int counter = ViewBag.SucCritCounter; }
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#insert-success-criteria').on("click", function (e) {
        $(this).closest('tr').prev('tr').find('.remove-success-criteria').remove();
        $(this).closest('tr').prev('tr').find('ul')
            .append(
                '<li>' +
                '@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SuccessCriteria[counter], new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control col-xs-12" } })' +
                '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove-success-criteria"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>' +
                '</li>');
            @{counter++; }
    });
});

jQuery(function($) {
    $('ul').on("click", "button.remove-success-criteria", function(e) {
        if (!$(this).closest('li').prev('li').hasClass('base-success-criteria')) {
            $(this).closest('li').prev('li')
                .append('<button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove-success-criteria"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>');
        }
             @{counter--; }
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});

</sript>
```

Comment: It not clear at all from the code why you need a 'global variable', but `@{ int counter = ViewBag.SucCritCounter; }` is assigning a value to a server side variable (which no longer exists when the page is sent to the view). If you want to update some static counter on the server then you need to use ajax to post a value to a controller method that updates it. If on the other hand, you can a client side counter, then its `var counter = '@ViewBag.SucCritCounter'; inside the scipt, which your can then increment using `counter++;`

Answer (score 0):

Add a key to `Web.config`

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="MY_GLOBAL_VALUE" value="1" />
</appSettings>
```

And obtain it by this way

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MY_GLOBAL_VALUE"];
```